# python passing parameter to a function

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I am not clear about the concept of passing lists as arguments to functions in python.

I've tried researching on this myself , didn't find adequate resources.

I want to implement a helper function which returns a number of random items from  a given list. (in django queryset)

However, the list may contain multiple rows and passing it by value to a function may result in an out of memory state, correct me if I'm wrong.

How then should I pass a list to a function ?

Comment: Try to take a look here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html and here http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/05/22/pythons-mutable-default-problem The idea is that passing parameters to function depends on theirs type.

Comment: How values are passed to functions does not depend on their type!  Whether you can modify that value depends on the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, there are names and values.   An assignment statement makes a name refer to a value.  An assignment never makes a copy, and assignment never changes a value.  It only changes what value a name refers to.  Passing an argument to a function is like an assignment: now the local name of the argument in the function refers to the value that was passed in, and copies are never made.  This mechanism of names referring to values, and assignments changing which value names refer to, is the same for all objects in Python, regardless of their type.

This gets confusing because of mutable and immutable values.  If you pass a mutable value (for example, a list) into a function, and change the value, then the caller's names that refer to that value will also see the changed value.  If you pass an immutable value into a function (for example, a string or number), then the value cannot be changed by anyone.

Comment: +1 - Understanding references & mutability should help the OP unmuddy the waters

Answer (score 3):

Everything in Python is an identifier.  For lists, you can think of the evaluation strategy as "call by reference".  It is actually named ["call by sharing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Comment: An identifier is a string, did you mean "reference"? And Python's calling convention is *not* pass by reference. Rule of thumb: If `def f(x): x = None` has any effect, it's pass by reference. In Python, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @delnan, thanks, I immediately deleted my answer and looked up what it should be called.

Comment: +1 for researching and finding the proper (although relatively rarely used - so rarely, in fact, that I usually forget it myself) term.

Comment: It can properly be called "call by reference", if you consider the `=` operator to be "(re)bind name", rather than "set variable", which is closer to the truth anyway. Rebinding a parameter should not change the value of another name, even if called by reference.

Comment: @delnan: by the way, they are "identifiers" and not "references" since `x += 5`, for example, doesn't change the memory pointed to by `x`, but rather rebinds the identifier.

Comment: @Neil: "Identifier" is a construct in the grammar and the parser. Pointing out that variables, member attributes, etc. in Python are merely pointers (also called references, that's not the same reference as in pass-by-reference) to objects is correct and important. I've heard people argue that we shouldn't talk about variables but about "names", and they have a point. But "identifier" is too connected to grammar/parsing IMHO.

Comment: @delnan:  I agree that we should talk about "names", and that's what I was trying to get at by saying "identifiers".  I didn't mean for it to be confused with grammatical element.  Next time, I'll say names.

Answer (score 3):

No. Passing a list to a function does not have any impact in terms of memory. Python does *not* copy the list.

Answer (score 2):

A full explanation of what **Ned Batchelder** said:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces